# Revert to default skin in DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke, skin

Today I was looking for a skin to edit but I accidently clicked apply button of a skin. That skin is for displaying videos. Now when I click any item in admin menu I am seeing my video page template and its completely empty. So now I can't do any changes in admin menus. I looked also in database but I can't find anything about it. Now I must to revert it. Any ideas? (Running DNN 6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apply command will replace the default skin in the settings of your website.
You could find this setting in PortalSettings table. Its name is "DefaultPortalSkin".
I suggest you to update its value with "[G]Skins/MinimalExtropy/index.ascx" which is the default value for DNN6. You also could update the "DefaultPortalContainer", if you need, with "[G]Containers/MinimalExtropy/Title_Red.ascx" for example.
FYI [G] means that the skin is located in /Portals/_default, [L] means that the skin is located in the portals folder.
In addition, don't forget to restart the corresponding application pool because of cache mechanisms which keep the old settings in memory.
You also could rename the folder of the current selected skins in order to force the website to load the default skin. It will permit you to go to the site settings to select the desired skin.